# How to animate a Hero Widget to the first element of a Carousel in another page?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, carousel

I'm trying to integrate both a Hero Widget and a Carousel in flutter.
I have a list of products from which onTap, the product's image animates to the details page via Hero Widget.

I've been able to implement a hero widget successfully without a carousel, however on the details page, I want to be able to view different pictures of the same product using a carousel.
How can I make the first item on the carousel have the same hero tag as from the page before just like in this image below?

[image]

**Page 1**

```
GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DetailsPage(
                              url: widget.url,
                              title: widget.url,
                              index: widget.index)),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Hero(
                    tag: "product-image+${widget.index}",
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                        placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                        image:
                            'https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6838599_preview.png',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))),
```

**Details Page**

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  final String title;
  final int index;
  DetailsPage({this.url, this.title, this.index});

  @override
  _DetailsPageState createState() => _DetailsPageState();
}

class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {
  List imgList = [
    'https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6838599_preview.png',
    'https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6838599_preview.png',
    'https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6838599_preview.png',
    'https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6838599_preview.png',
  ];
  int _current = 0;

  List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
    List<T> result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
    }
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Details',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'OpenSansLight',
                fontSize: 26,
                color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1.color),
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: height,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Hero(
                tag: "product-image+${widget.index}",
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  height: 200.0,
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                            widget.url ??
                                'https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6838599_preview.png',
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.contain)),
                ),
              ),
              CarouselSlider(
                options: CarouselOptions(
                    height: 200.0,
                    initialPage: 0,
                    reverse: false,
                    autoPlay: false,
                    enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                   
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    onPageChanged: (index, fn) {
                      setState(() {
                        _current = index;
                      });
                    }),
                items: imgList.map((imgUrl) {
                  return Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),),
                        child: 
                        
                        Image.network(
                          imgUrl,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: map<Widget>(imgList, (index, url) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 30.0,
                    height: 2.0,
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      color:
                          _current == index ? Colors.deepPurple : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A rather silly question. I managed to do it without much thinking. I just wrapped the Hero Widget on the Carousel slider

```
 Container(
        height: height,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Hero(
                        tag: "product-image+${widget.index}",
                        child: CarouselSlider(
                          options: CarouselOptions(
                              height: 200.0,
                              enlargeCenterPage: true,
                              enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
                              initialPage: 0,
                              reverse: false,
                              autoPlay: false,
                              enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              onPageChanged: (index, fn) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _current = index;
                                });
                              }),
                          items: imgList.map((imgUrl) {
                            return Builder(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return Image.network(
                                  imgUrl,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: map<Widget>(imgList, (index, url) {
                          return Container(
                            width: 30.0,
                            height: 2.0,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              color: _current == index
                                  ? Colors.deepPurple
                                  : Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Guess I was just afraid for nothing :D